# Unable to convert String to Long in Velocity Template

Tags: string, apache, velocity, long-integer, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a string value to long. As the number is too big for integer. $Integer.parseInt normally works but in this case, it saying the number is too big.

I tried 
`$Long.parseLong($variable)` or 
`$variable.longValue()`

The line of code is:

```
#set ($cos= $Long.parseLong($kbpsValue) / 1000)
```

When i print the value of `$cos`, it just prints the variable name.
The value of `kbpsValue` is `4451400000`.

Comment: You can try use math tool:https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.3/generic/MathTool.html#div()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Long` doesn't exist in VTL. And `String.toLong()` doesn't exist in Java. If the [conversion tool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ConversionTool.html) is available in the context, you can try:

```
$conv.toNumber($variable)
```

which relies upon the [NumberFormat.parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method.